# Javascript performance when calling functions within html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm faced with performance issues when calling an "onFocus" function within an html tag. I normally don't call functions in this manner, but I am not working with my own code.

Using: jQuery 1.4.2

I have two questions:

1.) Does calling functions within html tags really decrease performance? For example:

```
    <input type="text" onFocus="javascript:moveCursorToEnd(this.id)" />
```

2.)  What I would like to do is move the cursor to the end of an input when the user focuses on the input field. However, the target device does not react properly(iPad 2 using Safari). The cursor still moves to the position that is clicked and it takes approx. 15 seconds for the function to finish.

I have not really found any clean, cross browser compatible ways to move the cursor to the end of an input field.

```
    function moveCursorToEnd(id){
      var currentElement=$("#"+id);
      var currentValue=currentElement.val();
      currentElement.focus().val(String.fromCharCode(35)).val(currentValue);
      }
```

Then I call the function like this:

```
    <input type="text" onFocus="javascript:moveCursorToEnd(this.id)" />
```

Is there a better way to do this, while sitll calling the function from an html tag?

Comment: I doubt this would have something to do with events attached inline. `focus()` within `onfocus` handler triggers a new `focus` event...

Comment: in terms of the cross-browser option. in my experience the best way ive found to do this is to store the input fields text in a variable.. clear out the input field, then write the stored value back into the input.. seems silly i know, but hasnt failed me yet

Comment: Both `onFocus` and `javascript:` are wrong.

Comment: Not using inline event handler attributes is not about performance, it's about [cleanliness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)!

Comment: @Bergi What's wrong with `onFocus`? HTML is not case-sensitive.

Comment: @haxxxton I've tried this as well, but the iPad simply puts the cursor where the user clicks. So if I click in front of the text, it moves the cursor there as well. It could be a Safari issue..

Comment: @Teemu: You're right, it'll still work, HTML is not XHTML. Still, the standard spelling is `onfocus`.

Comment: @bralligator, if you're immediately removing all of the content of the cursor and then readding it.. the 'place' that was clicked is reset.. you may need to look at adding a short delay (~100ms) before re-applying the content however

Comment: @bralligator Not only in Safari, you've created an infinite event loop when you focusing the same element within a focus handler.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for pointing this out. Didn't realize!

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

changed the moveCursorToEndFunction, and trigger the function with "onclick". For some reason, using onfocus took about 8 seconds to load the iPad on screen keyboard.

```
     function moveCursorToEnd(id){
     var currentElement=$("#"+id);
     var currentValue=currentElement.val();
     currentElement.val(String.fromCharCode(35)).val(currentValue); 
     }
```